# Unable to copy alpha channel using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have two tif images - [input.tif](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7oe5h8ylocjhwdp/input.tif?dl=0) and [test.tif](https://www.dropbox.com/s/41x73u32dphmp3g/test.tif?dl=0) - and what I want to achieve is apply alpha channel of the first image to the second one. This is what I do now, using ImageMagick:

```
C:\Images> magick input.tif -alpha extract alpha.pgm
C:\Images> magick test.tif alpha.pgm -compose copyalpha -composite output.tif
```

When, however, I try to open output.tif, I get a message that the image is corrupt.

Comment: It works fine on my machine with **ImageMagick** v7.0.5. What program gives you the error message and what is the error message? What happens if you use **ImageMagick** to convert the supposedly corrupt image to a JPEG, does that work? Try running `identify -verbose output.tif` and clicking `edit` under your answer and pasting in the output - maybe IM has created a style of TIF that your reader program dislikes...

Comment: I'm using `ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16` on Windows 7.

Comment: As for a program, that gives this error message - it just happens when I double-click on the output.tif image and try to open it in a standard image viewer. I should add, that when I do the same with input.tif and test.tif, I get no errors.

Answer (score 3):

try adding -alpha off in your second command

```
C:\Images> magick input.tif -alpha extract alpha.pgm
C:\Images> magick test.tif alpha.pgm -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite output.tif
```

Or you can do it in one command as:

```
C:\Images> magick test.tif ( input.tif -alpha extract ) -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite output.tif
```